# How can I access Python which I installed with Anaconda directly from command prompt?

Tags: python, anaconda, command-prompt

I installed Python 3.7.0 with Anaconda 5.3.0. I could run the python prompt directly from Windows' command prompt by typing "python" or "python3" when I installed it by itself but installed this way, I can only access it from Anaconda command prompt which also I cannot run directly from Windows' cmd. How can I access python and/or anaconda(if possible) directly from cmd?

Comment: You need to update your system path to be able to find the python binaries, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check where is your Anaconda path. In Windows 10, you can commonly find it in:

`C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\<name_of_env>\python.exe`

You can simply call this from `cmd` or add it to your user/system variables so it's easier to access. For doing this in Windows 10: Press `Win+X`, then `Y`, then search for `Environment variables` and click the option that says `Edit environment variables for your account`. Then, set variable `PYTHONPATH` to your Anaconda environment. Another way to do this:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\<path_to_your_env>
```

Comment: I just added the python directory to my "path" variable. It worked for me.